# Can QEMU catch accesses to non-existing RAM on a Cortex-M processor?

Tags: qemu

is it possible to have QEMU report read or write accesses to non-existing RAM for a Cortex-M machine? Maybe a log function or a special option when building QEMU?
After all, it gets passed the address map - so it shouldn't be too difficult to detect this situation (of course this incurs a run-time cost).
All I found in the sources was
"Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x"
but nothing comparable for reading or writing.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
M'

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a QEMU with the "Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM" message then it's a pretty old one and you should probably be looking at a newer version, especially if you're digging into its source code.

Anyway, it is in theory possible but it isn't currently an implemented feature. You could probably get 90% of the way there by enabling the DEBUG_UNASSIGNED printf()s in softmmu/memory.c. A proper solution would require implementing suitable tracepoints instead.